# Why are rational numbers suddenly appearing in JSON/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rational-number

I use Rails to generate JSON for a javascript charting library (High Charts). There are a few places where I use integer arithmetic to calculate percentages in bar charts like this (simplified example):

```
def to_json
 data.map{|numerator, denominator| numerator * 100 / denominator }
end
```

This server has been running without problems for several years but, just in the last couple of weeks, this has started to fail occasionally because it generates a `Rational` number instead of a `Fixnum` (eg. `2700/50` instead of `54`). This breaks because the JSON parser in the browser does not understand the rational number.

The fix is easy (call `to_i` or `round` on the result) but I am confused as to why this suddenly started happening after 4 years and why it only happens on some Passenger instances on a single server on my web farm. The web machines are identical (as far as I know).

My four part question:

1. Is there a more idiomatic way to compute percentages in Ruby?
2. What are the rules for when Ruby generates a rational rather than a fixnum?
3. Why did this suddenly start happening?
4. Why would it only happen on some instances of my rails server?

Version details:

- ruby 2.2.2
- Rails 3.2.22
- passenger-5.0.21
- Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Comment: Are the rails and ruby versions same on the both instances?

Comment: All the web server instances have identical software deployed with capistrano on ubuntu. An added wrinkle: when the rationals start appearing, I can restart apache and it will go back to integers for a few hours and then the rationals appear again.

Comment: Can you give more details about the version you are using and the instances? That will help in solving the issue.

Comment: Edited to add version details.